# How to give deploy dependencies in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm working on multi-project build using gradle. The projects are developed independently ( in svn each project is in a different branch ). Each project is publish to repository and some other project might need one of this published project to be deployed ( in jboss ) before deploying that project. So the idea is to get the publish artifact from that project and deploy without checking out that particular branch. 
I want to know how to do this using gradle, (Is it possible to declare a deployment dependency ? )

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try and use the [gradle-arquillian](https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin) plugin, which may be bundled with the core Gradle distribution at some point. The other option is to script your own solution. If you decide to go with the latter, you only really need to figure out the deployment part, as fetching the artifacts is trivial (see "Working with dependencies" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).